# QT UTC linux Clock skew detected. Your build may be incomplete

Tags: c++, linux, qt, datetime

I have a code which I am writing it in QT (C++) where I want to display a date on a dateTime display on the GUI.. I get the time from another component and then I parse it into argument list and then I use Qprocess to run date - u command .. anyhow it seems like my make doesn't like what I am doing because it prints out this error:

```
QT UTC linux Clock skew detected. Your build may be incomplete.
```

the whole purpose of what I am doing is to update the UTC time of my linux computer according to the value I am getting and then gets that date using QT code to get the computer UTC time

here is part of the code :

```
    if(month<10)
{
    argument  = "0"+ argument + QString::number(month);
}
else
{
    argument =  argument + QString::number(month);
}
if(day<10)
{
    argument = "0"+ argument + QString::number(day);
}
else
{
    argument =  argument + QString::number(day);
}
if(hourUTC<10)
{
    argument =  "0" + argument + QString::number(hourUTC);
}
else
{
    argument =  argument + QString::number(hourUTC);
}
if(minUTC<10)
{
    argument =  "0"+ argument + QString::number(minUTC);
}
else
{
    argument =  argument + QString::number(minUTC);
}
argument =  argument + QString::number(year);

argument =  argument +  ".";

if(secUTC<10)
{
    argument =  "0"+ argument + QString::number(secUTC);
}
else
{
    argument =  argument + QString::number(secUTC);
}
//argument =  argument + QString::number((qint32)qRound(msUTC/ 1000.0));

argumentlist << argument;

qDebug() << argumentlist;

QProcess* proc = new QProcess();

// Change system date and time "date -u MMDDhhmmYYYY.ss" in tha application the date is created dynamically
proc->start(program, argumentlist);
proc->waitForFinished();
m_pOi->setTime();
```

any idea how can I force the change in time to my compute ? and yea I do run the code as a super user !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this error happens when your file times are newer than your system clock. `make` warns you that it may not be building everything correctly because of this. `touch`ing all your files should sort out the problem.

One of the causes is an SCM system that preserves file times and is ahead of your system clock.

Comment: Right answer. Your build system check last modification time of your source files to point out what to compile and what is up-to-date. So it's a good idea to rebuild your project every time instead of incremental build to be sure that everything is built correctly when you're making such experiments with the system clock

Comment: I tried the touch command on the files and I got this error when I recompiled e: Warning: File `OBY_GUI.pro' has modification time 422 s in the future

Comment: make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.